# One point following another moving in a straight line?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, curves

There is a plane with two points on it, let's say A and B.

A starts at an arbitrary constant point, let's say $(0, 0)$, and $B$ at a point that needs to be tested, which we'll call $(c, d)$.

A moves upwards in a straight line at speed $V$. At any given point in time, $B$ will move at that same speed $V$ from wherever it is at that moment towards wherever $A$ is at the same time until $B$ contacts $A$, if that will ever happen at all. In what range of points must $B$ start in order to ever catch $A$?

I've determined (at least I think) that, for $B$, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(A) - y(B)}{x(A) - x(B)} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$ and that if $B$ starts below $A$, or is ever at a point below $A$, it will never reach $A$. Also, for $A$, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{V}{0}$ which is undefined, though $\frac{dy}{dt} = V$, and $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$. Also, for $A, x = 0$ and $y = Vt$, where $t$ is time.

How can one determine if $B$ will reach $A$, given a starting point $(c, d)$? Can equations, likely using integrals, be formed to show the $x$ and $y$ values of $B$ as functions of $t$? If so, how?

Comment: Are you sure that this question is about the software *Mathematica*? Your question may be more appropriate in http://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Software Mathematica? Oh sorry, I misunderstood the purpose of this stack. Is there a way to transfer a question w/o rewriting it?

Comment: I'll move this to math.SE, but to help you anyway: what you're interested in is called a [pursuit curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html).

Answer (score 1):

The points meet at some time $t \geq 0$ if and only if the initial position of $B$ is $(0,y_0)$ for some $y_0 \geq 0$. In other words, $B$ must start directly above $A$.

We may assume that $V=1$ since we can speed up or slow down time by a constant factor. (If rigor is desired here we can use what Jack Lee calls the "rescaling lemma" in *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (Lemma 9.3). That book is way overkill for this problem, but I don't know a more appropriate reference.)

Let $(x_B(t), y_B(t))$ be the position vector of $B$ at time $t \geq 0$. The corresponding velocity vector is

$$
(x_B', y_B')
= \left(\frac{-x_B}{\sqrt{x_B^2 + (y_B - t)^2}}, \frac{-(y_B - t)}{\sqrt{x_B^2 + (y_B - t)^2}}\right).
$$

My approach will be to make the change of coordinates $\tilde y = y - t$. This corresponds to transforming to a coordinate system that moves with $A$ so that $A$ remains fixed at the origin. The velocity of $B$ in this new coordinate system is
$$
(x_B', \tilde y_B')
= (x_B', y_B' - 1)
= \left(\frac{-x_B}{\sqrt{x_B^2 + \tilde y_B^2}},
        \frac{-\tilde y_B}{\sqrt{x_B^2 + \tilde y_B^2}} - 1 \right).
$$
As the velocity only depends explicitly on the position, the trajectory $(x_B(t), \tilde y_B(t))$ is an [integral curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve) of the vector field
$$
F(x,\tilde y)
= \left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2 + \tilde y^2}},
        \frac{-\tilde y}{\sqrt{x^2 + \tilde y^2}} - 1 \right)
$$
on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Note that

1. Each integral curve exists either (i) until it hits the origin or (ii) forever (this can be deduced from the fact that $F$ is bounded and continuous, using among other tools the [Peano existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem)); and
2. For $x \neq 0$, the ratio $\displaystyle\frac{F_2}{F_1} = \frac{\tilde y + \sqrt{x^2 + \tilde y^2}}{x}$ of the components of $F$ (i.e. the slope of $F$) is constant along each radial ray of constant polar angle, and is positive iff $x > 0$ and negative iff $x < 0$.

Now, if $B$ starts directly above $A$ then they will obviously collide. And as you noted, if $B$ is ever side-by-side with or below $A$ it will never catch up.

The remaining case is the one where $x_B(0) \neq 0$ and $\tilde y_B(0) > 0$. Because $\tilde y'_B(t) < -1$ when $\tilde y_B(t) > 0$, the trajectory reaches the line $\tilde y = 0$ in finite time. Let $T > 0$ be the earliest such time.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $(x_B(T), \tilde y_B(T)) = (0,0)$. We define sequences $(t_n)_{n \geq 0}$ of times and $(u_n)_{n \geq 0}$ of $\tilde y$-coordinates (plus, for convenience, $x_n = x_B(t_n)$ and $\tilde y_n = \tilde y_B(t_n)$) as follows.

The initial conditions will be $t_0 = 0$ and $u_0 = \tilde y_B(0)$.

Next, suppose $t_n < T$ and $u_n > 0$ are such that $(x_n, \tilde y_n)$ and $(x_0, u_n)$ are at the same polar angle. In particular we have $$\operatorname{sgn} x_n = \operatorname{sgn} x_0 \neq 0,$$ where $\operatorname{sgn}$ is the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). Choose a $t_{n+1} \in (t_n, T)$ such that
\begin{equation} \tag{*} \label{ratio}
\frac{\tilde y_n}{x_n}
= \frac{F_2(x_{n+1}, \tilde y_{n+1})}{F_1(x_{n+1}, \tilde y_{n+1})}
\equiv \frac{\tilde y_{n+1} + \sqrt{x_{n+1}^2 + \tilde y_{n+1}^2}}{x_{n+1}};
\end{equation}
such a time exists due to [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem). Then
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{sgn} x_{n+1}
&= \operatorname{sgn}(\tilde y_n / x_n) && \text{(by item 2 of the earlier list since $x_{n+1} \neq 0$)} \\
&= \operatorname{sgn} x_n && \text{(since $t_n < T \implies \tilde y_n > 0$)} \\
&= \operatorname{sgn} x_0.
\end{align*}
Thus, there is a (unique) $u_{n+1} > 0$ such that $(x_0, u_{n+1})$ has the same polar angle as $(x_{n+1}, \tilde y_{n+1})$. This finishes the construction.

However, observe that by \eqref{ratio} and item 2,
$$
\frac{u_n}{x_0}
= \frac{u_{n+1} + \sqrt{x_0^2 + u_{n+1}^2}}{x_0},
$$
which implies $u_{n+1} < u_n - \lvert x_0 \rvert$. This means that $u_n < u_0 - n \lvert x_0 \rvert$ for all $n > 0$, contradicting the fact that the $u_n$ are all positive.

Thus even in this last case $B$ eventually falls side-by-side with $A$, after which $B$ is condemned to make a futile chase from below forever.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand this, but are you basically saying that if A and B don't start on the same x they cannot meet?

Comment: A bit stronger than that. $B$ has to start directly above $A$.

Answer (score -1):

A starts from (0,0)and B starts from (c,d)and both A and B move at a speed of V. After time t,say, B catches up with A at a point, say, (a,b).Then (a,b) is at a distance Vt from the origin and from (c,d).
Therefore, B can start from any point on the circle centered (a,b) and passing through the origin in order that it can meet A at (a,b). 
(a,b) is at a distance of Vt both from the origin and from (c,d).

Comment: I think you're answering it assuming B is moving in a straight line, but it isn't. B moves in a pursuit curve, following the path of A.

Answer (score -1):

If B chases A with higher speed then eventually it can meet or overtake A. Else never.
This comes from time t = Distance to be covered/ *relative* speed.

Comment: "Distance to be covered" changes constantly, because A is also moving, and not parallel to B. A moves in a straight line and B moves in a pursuit curve following A.

Comment: Distances are along arc.